# Close window A by clicking a button on window B

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I have window A with some graphs and a button "NEXT". When the user presses the button, window B opens with some questions about the graphs on window A. It also has a button "Done". Once "Done" is pressed, window A, and B close.

Problem: I don't get window A to close and no error messages in the console.

Window A:

```
class Window_A(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window_A, self).__init__(parent,flags=Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint|Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window A")
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        # Load the images
        [...]

        #"NEXT button"
        self.b_next = QPushButton("NEXT")

        self.b_next.clicked.connect(self.open_next)

        #Layout
        [...]

  def close_win(self):
      self.close()
    
  def open_next(self):
      self.next= Window_B()
      self.next.show()
```

Window B:

```
class Window_B(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window_B, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window_B")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #define text labels
        [...]

        #done button
        self.d_button = QPushButton("Done")
        self.d_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.d_button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
    

        #layout for text (questions)
        [...]

    def on_click(self):
        Window_A().close_win()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your window_B code, you do not know the reference to the correct window_A object.
So your line:

```
def on_click(self):
    Window_A().close_win()
```

creates a new Window_A object, calls its close function immediately, and this objects is garbage collected asap.

You will need to pass a reference to A in the B object.
For instance:

in window_A.py

```
    def open_next(self):
        self.next= Window_B()
        self.next.show()
        self.next.ref_to_close_father = self
```

in window_B.py

```
    def on_click(self):
        self.ref_to_close_father.close_win()
```

This should be better (but your example is not *reproducible*, so there might be another problem).

By the way,

```
self.d_button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
```

could simply be

```
self.d_button.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Comment: referencing did the trick, thanks! Learned something new again.

Comment: It's also worth noticing that `Window_A().close_win()` does *not* create any reference for the new instance, not even in the local scope. It almost as doing `list().append('x')`: you didn't assign no reference for the new instance, so whatever you do with it, it gets garbage collected as soon as the last function (`close_win()`) returns. Do consider that in *some* cases it would work (obviously, I'm talking about the new instance, not closing the existing one): calling `Window_A(self).show()` will create an implicit reference to the parent, so a new window will be actually shown.